# What is a forkJoin alternative that allows parallel requests to complete if one of them fails

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to run some requests in parallel using `forkJoin` and combine their results as shown below.
However, when one of the requests fails, the rest of the subscriptions are automatically cancelled by the browser. What is a simple alternative to `forkJoin` that lets me run requests in parallel and if one subscription fails, the rest are allowed to complete?

```js
const posts = this.http.get("https://myApi.com/posts?userId=1");
const albums = this.http.get("https://myApi.com/albums?userId=1");

forkJoin([posts, albums]).subscribe((result) => {
  this.print(result[0], result[1]);
});

print(res1, res2) {
  const message = res1.text + res2.text;
  console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: How would that work exactly? If one of the requests fails, a fallback value would have to be provided for it. Apply error handling with a fallback value to each request

Comment: `forkJoin([posts, albums].map($o => $o.pipe(catchError(() => [])))).subscribe(...)` should do the trick here. Note that this provides an empty array as the default for each, a completely arbitrary decision.

Comment: Although the accepted answer is very good, and probably would have been accepted anyway. It is considered better practice to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer to give everyone in all time zones the opportunity to respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that using `forkJoin`, however, you have to handle the errors for each sub `Observable` separately using `catchError` to prevent canceling the stream if any error occurred.

You can try something like the following:

```js
// import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';

const posts = this.http
  .get('https://myApi.com/posts?userId=1')
  .pipe(catchError((err) => of(err)));
const albums = this.http
  .get('https://myApi.com/albums?userId=1')
  .pipe(catchError((err) => of(err)));

forkJoin([posts, albums]).subscribe((result) => {
  this.print(result[0], result[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function like

```js
forkJoinReplaceErrors<T,R>(
  observables: Observable<T>[],
  ifError: ObservableInput<R>
) {
  const fReturnIfError = () => ifError;
  const array = observables.map(
    o$ => o$.pipe(
      catchError(fReturnIfError)
    )
  );
  return forkJoin(...array);
}
```

and then use that instead of `forkJoin`. Then it's more reusable and can be unit tested.